# How to display names starting with 's' and then names having 's'

Tags: mysql, pattern-matching

I need to select  names starting with  's' and names having 's'.for that I used the below command:

```
select staffname from staffreg where staffname like 's%' or staffname like '%s%'
```

But I need to display the names starting with 's' first and then names having 's' only.

for example table may contains:

Sushama
Asha
Suresh

I need to display 'Asha' after Sushama and Suresh:

Comment: try adding "order by staffname desc" in you query

Comment: Is the order between `Sushama` and `Suresh` important? Also, note that `%s%` includes `s%`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select staffname from staffreg where staffname like 's%' or staffname like '%s%' order by
    case
        when lower(staffname) like 's%' THEN 1
        else 2
    end;
```